# How to match a string which starts with either a new line or after a comma?

Tags: regex, perl

My string is `$tables="newdb1.table1:100,db2.table2:90,db1.table1:90"`. My search string is db1.table1 and my aim is to extract the value after `:` (i.e `90` in this case).

I am using:

```
if ($tables =~ /db1.table1:(\d+)/) { print $1; }
```

but the problem is it is matching `newdb1.table1:100` and printing `100`.

Can you please give my a regular expression to match a string which either starts with a newline or has comma before it.

Answer (score 6):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
if ($tables =~ /\bdb1.table1:(\d+)/) { print $1; }
         here __^^
```

Comment: Word boundaries also match dot's so it will match new.db1.table1 making @aragaer 's answer a better solution in this case. But i have to agree that in most cases this would work better.

Comment: Perhaps adding cosmetics, `/\b db1.table1:(\d+) /x`

Answer (score 2):

`if ($tables =~ /(^|,)db1.table1:(\d+)/) { print $2; }`

Comment: If you make the `(^|,)` group non capturing like so `(?:^|,)` there is no need for changing the print statement.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just prefer this, simpler way.

Comment: thanks aragaer, I tried this but i used [] instead of () if ($tables =~ /[^|,]db1.table1:(\d+)/) { print $2; }  thank you very much

Comment: @KarthikAppigatla Using `[^|,]` means match any single character that is not a vertical bar or comma, not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, that is to match just after the start of the string or a comma, you want a positive look-behind assertion. You may be tempted to write a pattern of

```
/(?<=^|,)db1\.table1:(\d+)/
```

but that may fail with an error of

```
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=^|,)db1\.table1:(\d+)/ ...
```

So hold the regex engine’s hand a bit by making the alternatives equal in length—tricky to do in the general case but workable here.

```
/(?<=^d|,)db1\.table1:(\d+)/
```

While we are locking it down, let’s be sure to bracket the end with a look-ahead assertion.

```
while ($tables =~ /(?<=^d|,)db1\.table1:(\d+)(?=,|$)/g) {
  print "[$1]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
[90]
```

You could also use `\b` for a regex word boundary, which has the same output.

```
while ($tables =~ /\bdb1\.table1:(\d+)(?=,|$)/g) {
  print "[$1]\n";
}
```

For the most natural solution, follow the [rule of thumb proposed by Randal Schwartz](http://perl.plover.com/flagbook/yak/Chi/slide066.html), author of *Learning Perl*. Use capturing when you know what you want to keep and `split` when you know what you want to throw away. In your case you have a mixture: you want to discard the comma separators, and you want to keep the digits after the colon for a certain table. Write that as

```
for (split /\s*,\s*/, $tables) {    # / to fix Stack Overflow highlighting
  if (my($value) = /^db1\.table1:(\d+)$/) {
    print "[$value]\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[90]
```

Comment: `/(?<=^.|,)db1\.table1:(\d+)/` will match "Xdb1.table1:100" which is wrong. Instead we can use common match to beginning of the string and look-behind for comma, like this: `/(?:^|(?<=,))db1\.table1:(\d+)/`. However we don't really care about _where_ we get our match as long as it is correct match. That's why my solution (with @B8vrede comment) would work.

Comment: @aragaer Incidental to the main point at the end of my answer, but fixed for completeness.